# How to make Ionic CLI show what files are generated when running `ionic g page MyPage`?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

It currently doesn't show up. This is what I want to see:

```
$ ionic g page About
√ Create www/app/about/about.html
√ Create www/app/about/about.js
√ Create www/app/about/about.scss
```

Currently using a Mac with OSX, using iTerm.

Comment: @Ivaro18 It's not a feature request. It says that on their docs. https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/cli/generate/ Do some research before you make a suggestion.

Comment: @Ivaro18 My friend, please watch this. It's already a feature. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R07W_RA4ano&t=0m39s

Comment: ok in that case I'll pull back my comments.